# Error while installing car Package

Tags: r, installation

I am trying to install car package but getting below error , can anyone help me to know what is the issue

> Warning in install.packages :   running command '"C:/Program
>   Files/R/R-3.3.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l ""
>   C:\Users\prajwal.dsilva\AppData\Local\Temp\9\Rtmpu2TGR0/downloaded_packages/car_2.1-5.tar.gz'
>   had status 1 Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
>   ‘car’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Have you tried some of the solution listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893230/installation-of-package-file-path-had-non-zero-exit-status-in-r)

Comment: Able to installed , I reinstalled r and later able to install car package, I reinstalled R in C drive instead of default (C: Program Files)

I think there is some issues as earlier I installed “memisc” before “car”, but not sure whether it causes issue