# I want install tidyverse package using: install.packages("tidyverse") . but it gives me errors below

Tags: r

```
install.packages("tidyverse") 
Installing package into ‘/Users/user/Library/R/3.3/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘callr’, ‘reprex’

There are binary versions available but the source versions
  are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
callr      1.0.0  2.0.3             FALSE
tidyverse  1.1.1  1.2.1             FALSE

installing the source packages ‘callr’, ‘reprex’, ‘tidyverse’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/callr_2.0.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 97453 bytes (95 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 95 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/reprex_0.1.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 22879 bytes (22 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 22 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidyverse_1.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 61647 bytes (60 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 60 KB

* installing *source* package ‘callr’ ...
** package ‘callr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘callr’
* removing ‘/Users/user/Library/R/3.3/library/callr’

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘callr’ had non-zero exit status

ERROR: dependency ‘callr’ is not available for package ‘reprex’
* removing ‘/Users/user/Library/R/3.3/library/reprex’

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘reprex’ had non-zero exit status

ERROR: dependency ‘reprex’ is not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/Users/user/Library/R/3.3/library/tidyverse’

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/mt/kdpgc7xx7nl4wl2g43877jb80000gn/T/RtmpSJkXIU/downloaded_packages’

> library(tidyverse)
Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’
```

Comment: Searching for the term '`xcrun: error: invalid active developer path`' led me to this post which might help: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/macos-sierra-invalid-active-developer-path

Answer (score 2):

You have the non-zero exit status error. That's answered [in another R thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893230/installation-of-package-file-path-had-non-zero-exit-status-in-r) which just means there was an error during installation. Specifically, the packages `callr` and `reprex` did not install. These are required packages for `tidyverse` which then subsequently did not install.

Generally it works for me after I restart the computer and try again. You can also try installing the `callr` and `reprex` packages individually before installing `tidyverse`.

As a last resort, you can search for the archive with the functions part of 'tidyverse' online and load them into R manually. This doesn't install the functions as part of a package but ends them into your global environment to make them available temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem as follows:

1. I update my R to version 3.4.4
2. I then use :  install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies=TRUE) as explained here : [Having trouble installing and loading tidyverse](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17626/having-trouble-installing-and-loading-tidyverse-no-dib-package)