# I cannot install the 'coin' package on R or RStudio on Mac OS Monterey Version 12.6 for `wilcox_effsize()`

Tags: r

I cannot tried installing the `coin` package so I can use the `wilcox_effsize()` for my dataset.

The problem -

```
> wilcox_effsize(data = runDataValidMeansA, formula = runtime ~ A.mode, p.adjust.method = "BH")
Error in required_package("coin") : 
  coin package needed to be installed before using this function. Type this in R: install.packages('coin')
```

What I tried - using `install.packages('coin')

```
> install.packages('coin')
Installing package into ‘/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/coin_1.4-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1225311 bytes (1.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.2 MB

* installing *source* package ‘coin’ ...
** package ‘coin’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
clang -I"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.2.1_2/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library/libcoin/include' -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/include -I/opt/homebrew/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c Helpers.c -o Helpers.o
clang -I"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.2.1_2/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library/libcoin/include' -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/include -I/opt/homebrew/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c StreitbergRoehmel.c -o StreitbergRoehmel.o
clang -I"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.2.1_2/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library/libcoin/include' -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/include -I/opt/homebrew/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c coin-init.c -o coin-init.o
clang -I"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.2.1_2/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library/libcoin/include' -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/include -I/opt/homebrew/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c vandeWiel.c -o vandeWiel.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.2.1_2/lib/R/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/lib -L/opt/homebrew/lib -o coin.so Helpers.o StreitbergRoehmel.o coin-init.o vandeWiel.o -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openblas/lib -lopenblas -L/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin21/12 -L/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/gcc -L/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current -lgfortran -lemutls_w -lquadmath -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.2.1_2/lib/R/lib -lR -lintl -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: -undefined dynamic_lookup may not work with chained fixups
ld: warning: could not create compact unwind for ___emutls_get_address: registers 23 and 24 not saved contiguously in frame
installing to /opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library/00LOCK-coin/00new/coin/libs
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library/mvtnorm/libs/mvtnorm.so':
  dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library/mvtnorm/libs/mvtnorm.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: '/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/11/libgfortran.5.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library/mvtnorm/libs/mvtnorm.so'
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/11/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.2.1_2/lib/R/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file)
Calls: <Anonymous> ... asNamespace -> loadNamespace -> library.dynam -> dyn.load
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘coin’
* removing ‘/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library/coin’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘coin’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/n6/dd96yfrs3wd9hnznyjqr4f280000gp/T/RtmpFEtn97/downloaded_packages’
```

I also tried installing using the source as was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893230/installation-of-package-file-path-had-non-zero-exit-status-in-r#:%7E:text=The%20non%2Dzero%20exit%20status,or%20you%20can%20download%20the%20.)

And I still get the same error.

```
> install.packages("libs/coin_1.4-2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
Installing package into ‘/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘coin’ ...
** package ‘coin’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
clang -I"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.2.1_4/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library/libcoin/include' -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/include -I/opt/homebrew/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c Helpers.c -o Helpers.o
clang -I"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.2.1_4/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library/libcoin/include' -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/include -I/opt/homebrew/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c StreitbergRoehmel.c -o StreitbergRoehmel.o
clang -I"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.2.1_4/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library/libcoin/include' -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/include -I/opt/homebrew/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c coin-init.c -o coin-init.o
clang -I"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.2.1_4/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library/libcoin/include' -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/include -I/opt/homebrew/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c vandeWiel.c -o vandeWiel.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.2.1_4/lib/R/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/lib -L/opt/homebrew/lib -o coin.so Helpers.o StreitbergRoehmel.o coin-init.o vandeWiel.o -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openblas/lib -lopenblas -L/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin21/12 -L/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current/gcc -L/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current -lgfortran -lemutls_w -lquadmath -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.2.1_4/lib/R/lib -lR -lintl -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: -undefined dynamic_lookup may not work with chained fixups
ld: warning: could not create compact unwind for ___emutls_get_address: registers 23 and 24 not saved contiguously in frame
installing to /opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library/00LOCK-coin/00new/coin/libs
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library/mvtnorm/libs/mvtnorm.so':
  dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library/mvtnorm/libs/mvtnorm.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: '/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/11/libgfortran.5.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library/mvtnorm/libs/mvtnorm.so'
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/11/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.2.1_4/lib/R/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file)
Calls: <Anonymous> ... asNamespace -> loadNamespace -> library.dynam -> dyn.load
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘coin’
* removing ‘/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.2/site-library/coin’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘libs/coin_1.4-2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling R but I still get the same error. Any workarounds to get `wilcox_effsize` to work?

My version of R is - R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23) -- "Funny-Looking Kid"

Comment: You are trying to install from source in both cases; the output and error are the same. Try `type = "binary"` in `install.packages` or, when asked in the console, say "No" to source.

Comment: You can also install from source using gcc to compile, rather than clang, following the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65251887/clang-7-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-for-macos-big-sur/65334247#65334247 (installed without error on my system using this config)